# What is the correct way to end a WEBrick server process after a timeout?

Tags: ruby, webrick

I'm trying to implement a small WEBrick server that ends itself when there are no requests after x number of seconds. However, I'm getting nowhere. My very first attempt at simply exiting after 2 seconds fails. Here's the simple code
that doesn't work.

```
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8000)
WEBrick::Utils::TimeoutHandler.register(2, Timeout::Error)
server.start
```

I thought that would simply exit the process after 2 seconds. Here's what actually happens:

```
[2020-01-19 15:41:10] INFO  WEBrick 1.4.2
[2020-01-19 15:41:10] INFO  ruby 2.5.1 (2018-03-29) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
[2020-01-19 15:41:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=16622 port=8000
[2020-01-19 15:41:12] ERROR Timeout::Error: execution timeout
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
```

And then the process keeps running. I have to ctrl-c to end it.

What's the correct way to shut down a server and end the process after a timeout?

Comment: Why even bother with webrick? The only reason it was used was that at one point it was the only server that required zero setup. Now that you can just plop puma, unicorn or thin into your gemfile and rock'n'roll there is no good reason to use webrick which is dismal at best.

Comment: It's just a small, experimental project to share with others. I'm not going to tell people they have to install a big framework just to run a few lines of experimental code. I wouldn't do it. WEBrick will serve my needs just fine if I can figure out the timeout issue.

Comment: "install a big framework". Uhm you just run `gem install puma`. And this doesn't work since the timeout handler is meant to timeout slow requests. Not kill the server after x seconds. '

Comment: So how do you kill the server after x seconds?